# Is the antichrist neither "good" nor "evil", or only from a perspective which rejects both terms?

Tags: nietzsche

Is the antichrist neither "good" nor "evil", or only from a perspective which rejects both terms? I haven't read much Nietzsche, but surely, I'm thinking, the former!

Comment: I think you'd have to define what you mean by The AntiChrist.

Comment: @barrycarter eh i just mean nietzsche. like the idea that he hypothesised the death of god, and marx proved it. ha :)